# A btter way to represent Same value given multiple values(C#3.0)

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a situation for which I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Consider the below cases

```
"BKP","bkp","book-to-price" (will represent) BOOK-TO-PRICE

"aop","aspect oriented program" (will represent) ASPECT-ORIENTED-PROGRAM
```

i.e. if the user enter BKP or bkp or book-to-price , the program should treat that as BOOK-TO-PRICE. The same holds good for the second example(ASPECT-ORIENTED-PROGRAM).

I have the below solution:

Solution:

```
if (str == "BKP" || str == "bkp" || str == "book-to-price" ) return "BOOK-TO-PRICE".
```

But I think that there can be many other better solutions .

Could you people please give some suggestion.(with an example will be better)

I am using C#3.0 and dotnet framework 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider using a `Dictionary<string,string>`, perhaps populated from a configuration file or database table, with alias to canonical name relationships.  Use a case insensitive key comparer.  For example,

```
var map = new Dictionary<string,string>( StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase );
map.Add( "bkp", "BOOK-TO-PRICE" );
map.Add( "book-to-price", "BOOK-TO-PRICE" );
map.Add( "aop", "ASPECT-ORIENTED-PROGRAM" );
map.Add( "aspect oriented program", "ASPECT-ORIENTED-PROGRAM" );
```

Then you only need, given, the key do an O(1) lookup to find the canonical name.

```
var name = map["bkp"];
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I would recommend.

Comment: Yeah, same here; since strings are immutable, there is no storage overhead (compared to other methods, even when the strings are large) as there would be in C.